# python regex with multiple recursive characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas series:

```
arr = pd.Series(['C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'CC', 'KEEP', 'ATC', 'CACACAC', 'CCCCCCCCACAGTTTATGTAG', 'C(2', 'Cor CC', 'AC or ACC'])
```

From it, I want to remove the elements `C(2`, `Cor CC` and `AC or ACC` using regex

So the criteria that I am trying to match are:

1. Start with a capital letter: `^[A-Z]`
2. Exclude any element that has a parenthesis in it: `[^\(]`
3. Exclude any element that has the string `or`

`arr.str.contains(r'^[A-Z][\(]')` will match  `C(2` whereas I can match `Cor CC` and `AC or ACC` with `arr.str.contains(r'\w*or.\w*'`.

I can then pop out these elements from my list, but I am trying to keep the elements of interest (i.e. without `C(2`, `Cor CC` and `AC or ACC`) using regular expression

Comment: Try `arr.str.contains(r'^[A-Z]\(|or')`

Comment: All you need to know is the concept of logical `OR` in regular expressions. You can use `|` to get that functionality. Then you can simply do `arr[~arr.str.contains(r'^[A-Z]\(|or')]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
arr[~arr.str.contains(r'^[A-Z]\(|or')]
```

**Details**

- `^[A-Z]\(` - an uppercase ASCII letter and `(` at the start of a string
- `|` - or
- `or` - an `or` substring

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FSbLx0/1).